# ld cannot find an installed library

Tags: linux

I am trying to install spice-gkt and at some point I reach this dead end.

**My setup:**
PC with ARM architecture;
Debian 7 running (altered version)

Error:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
/usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
- add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
during execution
- add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
during linking
- use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
- have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/spice-controller'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 spice-controller.h '/usr/local/include/spice-controller'
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk/controller'
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk/controller'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk/controller'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk'
CCLD libspice-client-glib-2.0.la
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcelt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [libspice-client-glib-2.0.la] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk'
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk'
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22/gtk'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cubie/Desktop/spice-gtk-0.22'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Spice is dependent of libcelt051, which is installed... So, don't really know what could be causing this.

Comment: Where is `libcelt.so` or `libcelt.a` located?

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig`? Did you edit `/etc/ld.so.conf`? Did you pass some `-L` flag to `gcc`?

Comment: Or it could it be that the symbolic link `libcelt-0.5.1.so` (*am guessing the full name as OP states **libcelt051** *) is missing a equivalent `libcelt.so`?

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin, i can't find those, instead, i have at /usr/local/bin libcelt051.so and libcelt051.a

Comment: @Bsile Starynkevitch i did run ldconfig, and haven't edited ld.so.conf, should i? Haven't passed any flags to gcc.

Comment: The problem is, Debian repo doesn't have the celt-0.5.1 and this is the compatible version with spice. It has only 0.7.1. 
I can see that the problem was originated at configure, as i didn't specified any directories. 
I have installed with those commands and it went smoothly

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin` is not used normally for libraries.

You need to install libcelt correctly. Either by installing it from your distro package manager or by downloading the required version and then compiling and installing it with the usual `./configure && make && sudo make install`.